# Mass Transit - How to Schedule a message using Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I've checked into the documentation regarding [Scheduling with Azure Service Bus](https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/azure-sb-scheduler.html), but I am not clear on how exactly to send a message from a "disconnected" Bus.

Here's how I've configured my Service that is processing messages on the server:

```
builder.AddMassTransit(mt =>
{
    mt.AddConsumers(cqrsAssembly);

    mt.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(x =>
    {
        x.RequiresSession = true;
        x.MaxConcurrentCalls = 500;
        x.MessageWaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        x.UseRenewLock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));
        x.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();

        var host = x.Host(serviceUri, h =>
        {
            h.SharedAccessSignature(s =>
            {
                s.KeyName = "key-name";
                s.SharedAccessKey = "access-key";
                s.TokenTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                s.TokenScope = TokenScope.Namespace;
            });

            h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        });

        x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"mt.myqueue", ep =>
        {
            ep.RequiresSession = true;
            ep.MaxConcurrentCalls = 500;
            ep.RemoveSubscriptions = true;

            ep.UseMessageRetry(r =>
            {
                r.Interval(4, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                r.Handle<TransientCommandException>();
            });

            ep.ConfigureConsumers(context);
        });
    });
});
```

I've explicitly called `UseServiceBusMessageScheduler()`.

In the project that is creating and sending messages to the queue (runs in a different context, so is done to "send only"), we have this:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(x =>
{
    x.RequiresSession = true;
    x.MessageWaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    x.UseRenewLock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));
    x.Send<ICommand>(s => s.UseSessionIdFormatter(ctx => ctx.Message.SessionId ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));


    var host = x.Host(serviceUri, h =>
    {
        h.SharedAccessSignature(s =>
        {
            s.KeyName = "key-name";
            s.SharedAccessKey = "key"; 
            s.TokenTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            s.TokenScope = TokenScope.Namespace;
        });
        h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    });

    EndpointConvention.Map<ICommand>(new Uri($"{serviceUri.ToString()}mt.myqueue"));
    EndpointConvention.Map<Command>(new Uri($"{serviceUri.ToString()}mt.myqueue"));
});
```

Now, to send a scheduled message, we do this:

```
var dest = "what?";
await bus.ScheduleSend(dest, scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc.Value, message);
```

I am unsure of what needs to be passed into the `destinationAddress`.

I've tried:
- `serviceUri`
- `{serviceUri}mt.myqueue"

But checking the queues, I don't see my message in either the base queue, the `skipped` queue or the `error` queue.

Am I missing some other configuration, and if not, how does one determine the destination queue?

Am using version `5.5.4` of Mass Transit, and every overload to `ScheduleSend()` requires it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, yes your Uri format is correct. In the end after formatting you need something like this :

```
new Uri(@"sb://yourdomain.servicebus.windows.net/yourapp/your_message_queue")
```

Also make sure you added when you configured your endPoint. (See the link below)

```
configurator.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
```

If you follow the Mass-Transit documentation, scheduling is done from a ConsumeContext. See [Mass-Transit Azure Scheduling](https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/azure-sb-scheduler.html)

```
public class ScheduleNotificationConsumer :
    IConsumer<AssignSeat>
{
    Uri _schedulerAddress;
    Uri _notificationService;

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<AssignSeat> context)
    {
        if(context.Message.ReservationTime - DateTime.Now < TimeSpan.FromHours(8))
        {
            // assign the seat for the reservation
        }
        else
        {
            // seats can only be assigned eight hours before the reservation
            context.ScheduleMessage(context.Message.ReservationTime - TimeSpan.FromHours(8), context.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

However in a use case we faced this week we needed to schedule from outside a consumeContext, or simply didn't want to forward the context down to where we scheduled. When using `IBusControl.ScheduleSend` we get no error feedback, but we also don't really get any scheduling done.
 After looking at what Mass-Transit does it turns out that from an IBusControl, it creates a new scheduling provider. Whereas from the Context it uses the ServiceBusScheduleMessageProvider.

So what we're doing now until we clean up this bit, is calling the ServiceBusScheduleMessageProvider outright.

```
        await new ServiceBusScheduleMessageProvider(_busControl).ScheduleSend(destinationUri
            , scheduleDateTime.UtcDateTime
            , Task.FromResult<T>(message)
            , Pipe.Empty<SendContext>()
            , default);
```

Hope it makes sense and helps a bit.

Comment: This was the missing piece.  Have updated our internal "messenger" to schedule messages using this technique, and works as expected.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this! Should this be reported as a bug or is this how it was intended to work?